# Music clearance forms

Tags: music, clearance

Hello,

Production is finished and now the US producer asks me to send the music clearance forms....?
I know these in Holland, but not in the US
Does anybody has an idea of where to get these forms, are they standard? should i make something up?

Answer (score 1):

Hey Bram,

You can ask the MU for clearance forms - give them a call and they'll be very helpful. That is, of course, if you paid MU rates!

If you're not talking about musicians for a session, you'll need clearance from whatever record label you have cleared the music with - it'll be a synchronisation & master usage license.

cheers
Tom